# HTML Canvas Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a problem with the initial width of the canvas.

What I have is a canvas element with a image background that's set to cover and than within the jquery the canvas width is set to the window.InnerWidth, the height is the width / 3. (this is to keep the background image in proportion as it's a banner and can't be cut off or stretched).

My problem is that the initial scale of the canvas is 300 x 150 and than it's calculated to the screen size. So what happens is, you have the banner being loaded at 300px x 150px and than after a second or so jumps to the correct size.

Here's an example of this: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVzpEp)

```
    function initHeader() {
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = width / 3;
    target = {
        x: width / 2,
        y: height / 3
    };

    canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
```

Through CSS I've tried setting the width of the canvas to 100%, it stretches the banner and creates a gap below the banner which I don't want.

I've tried everything I could think of and just can't come up with a valid solution.

Any advice would be greatly appreacited!

Comment: for starters, the width/height ratio for your image is closer to 3.28,. Start there.

Comment: That wasn't the actual banner, just picked something for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it take some delay to resize image? So don't init it when canvas not resize yet.

```
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
canvas.style.backgroundImage = "...."
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you, creates a much better effect than the image jumping around.